# Problems with 404 error page

Tags: html, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404

Im trying to divert to a 404 error page:

Here is the .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks


RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.MYSITE\.co.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://MYSITE.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]

#enable hiding cfm extension
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /(.+/)?index(\.cfm)?(\?.*)?\  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+/)?index(\.cfm)?$ /%1 [R=301,L]

#RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
#RewriteRule ^(.+)\.cfm$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}.cfm [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}.cfm -f
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}.cfm [QSA,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /404.cfm
```

However it is not directing to the 404.cfm page.

Any suggestions??

Comment: What is it doing instead?

Comment: Its bringing up the generic server file not found screen